# Was Lister's origin decided at the beginning?

Tags: time-travel, red-dwarf

In some of the earlier seasons of *[Red Dwarf](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094535/)*, David Lister tells of how, as a baby, he was found in a cardboard box under a pool table.

Then at some point in the seventh season, it was revealed that Lister was in fact

> his *own biological father*, conceived by himself and an alternate universe incarnation of his girlfriend Christine Kochanski and then sent back in time to ensure he lived his life the way history played out to be.

Was this something the writers had planned from the start?

Comment: I very much doubt it. Red Dwarf operates on rule of funny with often little regard for internal continuity. A famous example is Lister having his appendix removed twice because the writers had forgotten they mentioned this in an early episode.

Comment: @skyjack I remember it shown being removed in Legion. Out of curiosity can you remember when it was otherwise mentioned?

Comment: @JonClements in the season two episode "Thanks for the Memories" lister gifts a memory to Rimmer of an old girlfriend called Lisa Yates. For a while Rimmer thinks this memory is real. When he discovers it is not he comments on how he thought it odd that he had his appendix out twice. We can deduce from this that both Lister and Rimmer had their appendix removed. Fast forward to season seven and lister is shown having his appendix removed by the character called legion.